# Is there a way to implement Dependency injection code with IOptions in AddCors's Anonymous Function delegate?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, cors

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47479517/6888123
@aluan-haddad Many Thanks to @aluan-haddad for his answer posting above.

Here is info about our technical development environment :

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
- .NET Core 3.1
- DevExpress v21.2.6 platform
- PostgreSQL 14.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
- Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core 2.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.15
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.15
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 5.0.15
- Microsoft.OpenApi 1.2.3
- Npgsql 5.0.12
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 5.0.10
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.3.0

Just to briefly summarize what @aluan-haddad aforementioned posting states,  an overload of `AddDbContext` takes an `Action<IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder>`.

I'm using `IOptions`, and I was able to start the configuration with:

```
services.Configure<APIConfigSettings>(options =>
    Configuration.GetSection(nameof(APIConfigSettings.APIConfig)).Bind(options));
```

Therefore, I was able to do the following:

```cs
// Code below is Using an overload of AddDbContext that takes an
// Action<IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder>. 
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>((provider, options) => {
    IOptions<APIConfigSettings> apiConfigSettings =
        provider.GetService<IOptions<APIConfigSettings>>();
    options.UseNpgsql(apiConfigSettings.Value
        .ConnectionDictionary["DefaultConnection"]);
});
```

Previously, I was configuring the applications Cross Origin Settings (Cors) using the following:

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    // name: APIAllowSpecificOrigins,
    options.AddPolicy(name: APIAllowedSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins(Configuration["BlahblahAllowedOriginUrlBlahBlah"])
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});
```

Unfortunately, the following code throws a compilation error:

```cs
services.AddCors((provider, options) =>
{
    IOptions<APIConfigSettings> apiConfigSettings =
        provider.GetService<IOptions<APIConfigSettings>>();
    // name: APIAllowSpecificOrigins,
    options.AddPolicy(name: APIAllowedSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins(apiConfigSettings.Value.AllowedOriginUrl1)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});
```

However, `AddCors` does not seem to have a similar overloaded method that at the very lease resembles takes an `Action<IServiceProvider, CorsOptions>` ?

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddCors' and
> the best extension method overload
> 'MvcCorsMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.AddCors(IMvcCoreBuilder,
> Action)' requires a receiver of type 'IMvcCoreBuilder'

Answer (score 2):

Given the source code for AddCors

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension methods for setting up cross-origin resource sharing services in an <see cref="IServiceCollection" />.
/// </summary>
public static class CorsServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds cross-origin resource sharing services to the specified <see cref="IServiceCollection" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection" /> to add services to.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> so that additional calls can be chained.</returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddCors(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }
 
        services.AddOptions();
 
        services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<ICorsService, CorsService>());
        services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<ICorsPolicyProvider, DefaultCorsPolicyProvider>());
 
        return services;
    }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds cross-origin resource sharing services to the specified <see cref="IServiceCollection" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection" /> to add services to.</param>
    /// <param name="setupAction">An <see cref="Action{CorsOptions}"/> to configure the provided <see cref="CorsOptions"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> so that additional calls can be chained.</returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddCors(this IServiceCollection services, Action<CorsOptions> setupAction)
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }
 
        if (setupAction == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(setupAction));
        }
 
        services.AddCors();
        services.Configure(setupAction);
 
        return services;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors/CorsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,348bfc06c6464201)

And the following from documentation for `IOptions`

```
services.AddOptions<MyOptions>("optionalName")
    .Configure<Service1, Service2, Service3, Service4, Service5>(
        (o, s, s2, s3, s4, s5) => 
            o.Property = DoSomethingWith(s, s2, s3, s4, s5));
```

[Use DI services to configure options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options#use-di-services-to-configure-options)

You can create you own extension that provides the desired functionality using already existing extensions.

```
public static class MyCorsServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static IServiceCollection AddCors(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IServiceProvider, CorsOptions> setupAction) {
        if (services == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }
 
        if (setupAction == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(setupAction));
        }
 
        services.AddCors();
        
        services.AddOptions<CorsOptions>()
            .Configure<IServiceProvider>(
                (options, sp) =>
                    setupAction(sp, options)
            );
 
        return services;
    }
}
```